# Problem with multi-threading and waiting on events

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, events, mutex

I have a problem with my code:

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

HANDLE event;
HANDLE mutex;

int runner = 0;

DWORD WINAPI thread_fun(LPVOID lpParam) {
    int* data = (int*)lpParam;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { //this loop necessary in order to reproduce the issue
        if ((data[2] + 1) == data[0]) { // if it is last thread 
            while (1) {
                WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
                if (runner == data[0] - 1) { // if all other thread reach event break
                    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
                    break;
                }
                printf("Run:%d\n", runner);
                ReleaseMutex(mutex);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            printf("Check Done:<<%d>>\n", data[2]);
            runner = 0;
            PulseEvent(event); // let all other threads continue
        }
        else { // if it is not last thread
            WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
            runner++;
            ReleaseMutex(mutex);
            printf("Wait:<<%d>>\n", data[2]);
            WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE); // wait till all other threads reach this stage
            printf("Exit:<<%d>>\n", data[2]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    SetEvent(event);
    int data[3] = {2,8}; //0 amount of threads //1 amount of numbers
    HANDLE t[10000];
    int ThreadData[1000][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0]; i++) {
        memcpy(ThreadData[i], data, sizeof(int) * 2); // copy amount of threads and amount of numbers to the threads data
        ThreadData[i][2] = i; // creat threads id
        LPVOID ThreadsData = (LPVOID)(&ThreadData[i]);
        t[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, thread_fun, ThreadsData, 0, NULL);
        if (t[i] == NULL)return 0;
    }
    while (1) {
        DWORD res = WaitForMultipleObjects(data[0], t, true, 1000);
        if (res != WAIT_TIMEOUT) break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0]; i++)CloseHandle(t[i]); // close all threads
    CloseHandle(event); // close event
    CloseHandle(mutex); //close mutex
    printf("Done");
}
```

The main idea is to wait until all threads except one reach the event and wait there, meanwhile the last thread must release them from waiting.

But the code doesn't work reliably. 1 in 10 times, it ends correctly, and 9 times just gets stuck in `while(1)`. In different tries, `printf` in `while` (`printf("Run:%d\n", runner);`) prints different numbers of runners (0 and 3).

What can be the problem?

Comment: In your question, you state that `data[2] + 1` is equal to the number of the current thread. Does that mean that `data` refers to a different memory location for all threads?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel No, every single thread has its own data:
`int ThreadData[1000][3];
...
memcpy(ThreadData[i], data, sizeof(int) * 2);
        ThreadData[i][2] = i;
        LPVOID ThreadsData = (LPVOID)(&ThreadData[i]);
        t[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, thread_fun, ThreadsData, 0, NULL);`

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the posted code. Therefore, I suspect that the problem is in the code that you are not showing us. If possible, please provide a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I added minimal example of my code

Comment: Have you verified that the new minimal code actually reproduces the problem? Does it still print `5` for `runner`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel there is still a problem, now it is print 0

Comment: Since your code now behaves differently than described in your question, I suggest that you update your question to reflect the changed behavior. You may also want to state whether the behavior is reliable or whether it changes sometimes, when you run the program several times. Does is sometimes print `5` or always `0` now?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, thatnks a lot! I edited my question

Comment: Although written mostly in the C idiom, this code is C++, not C.  Tags updated.

Comment: In the most recent edit to your question, you deleted lots of unnecessary code (which was good), but you also deleted a lot of explanation of the code. You may want to consider restoring some of these explanations, if they still are relevant.

Comment: Why are you setting the event to signalled immediately after creating it, by writing `SetEvent (event);`? Because of this, at least on the first iteration of the loop, when `j == 0`, the first worker thread won't wait for the second worker thread.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel oh I make event non signal after creation, and it works correctly. Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: @AndreasWenzel unfortunately, I don't know how to like you there(

Comment: No problem. I hope you now understand the importance of a [mre]. It was not possible to answer your original question, because, as I suspected, the problem was in the code that you were not showing us.

Comment: You can only accept answers, not comments. If I had provided a solution as an answer instead of a comment, then you would have been able to accept it (and also upvote it, because you now have over 15 reputation points).

Comment: I have now created my own answer to your question. You should be able to accept and upvote it now.

Comment: In my opinion, it was not necessary to delete your answer. I'm not sure, but I believe that this caused you to lose the 10 points that you got from my upvote. Therefore, you may want to undelete your answer to get these points back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we found out in the comments section, the problem was that although the event was created in the initial state of being non-signalled

```
event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
```

it was being set to the signalled state immediately afterwards:

```
SetEvent(event);
```

Due to this, at least on the first iteration of the loop, when `j == 0`, the first worker thread wouldn't wait for the second worker thread, which caused a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Also, the following issues with your code are worth mentioning (although these issues were not the reason for your problem):

1. According to the [Microsoft documentation on `PulseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-pulseevent), that function should not be used, as it can be unreliable and is mainly provided for backward-compatibility. According to the documentation, you should use [condition variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/condition-variables) instead.
2. In your function `thread_fun`, the last thread is locking and releasing the mutex in a loop. This can be bad, because mutexes are not guaranteed to be fair and it is possible that this will cause other threads to never be able to acquire the mutex. Although this possibility is mitigated by you calling `Sleep(10);` once in every loop iteration, it is still not the ideal solution. A better solution would be to use a condition variable, so that the thread only checks for changes of the variable `runner` when another thread actually signals a possible change. Such a solution would also be better for performance reasons.